# How to add env variable to Hasura Docker container

Tags: docker, hasura

I have an env file with

```
HASURA_GRAPHQL_DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:postgrespassword@postgres:5432/postgres
HASURA_GRAPHQL_ENABLE_CONSOLE=true
HASURA_GRAPHQL_DEV_MODE=true
HASURA_GRAPHQL_ADMIN_SECRET=mysecretpassword
HASURA_GRAPHQL_JWT_SECRET={"type":"RS256","jwk_url":" ..... "issuer":"https://securetoken.googl>
```

I added this to my env file

HASURA_GRAPHQL_UNAUTHORIZED_ROLE=anonymous

How do I reload the container so the new line will be applied without losing any data or metadata?

I started my container with

```
docker run -itd --env-file /root/hasura.env --name hasura --restart unless-stopped --net host hasura/graphql-engine:latest graphql-engine serve
```

Comment: As long as you don't shut down your container running postgres, you should be fine. No data is stored in the hasura container, it connect to the postgres db container where it stores the data.